# Javascript detect keyspressed

Tags: javascript, html, key, mouseevent, keypress

I am trying to write a program that detects mouse movement and keys pressed conditions.

If run with html, this java script program can detect the mouse moving. I applied a similar strategy and found out that 'keydown' is the correct command to use, yet when I run the program, the keys are not changing the output to "keys are pressed."

```
var timer;
// mousemove code
var stoppedElement = document.getElementById("stopped"); 

function mouseStopped() { // the actual function that is called
stoppedElement.innerHTML = "Mouse stopped";
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  stoppedElement.innerHTML = "Mouse moving";
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(mouseStopped, 300);
});


//keypress code
var keysElements = document.getElementById('keyPressed');

function keysPressed() {
  keysElement.innerHTML = "Keys not Pressed";
}


window.addEventListener("keydown", function() {

  keysElement.innerHTML = "Keys Pressed";
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout("keysPressed", 300);
});
```

I have a feeling that my addEventListener for keydown isn't the correct method to use. Which would be the correct js method for checking for keys pressed?
Thanks

Comment: looks like a typo, keyElement and keyElements

Comment: You're actually looking for the correct *event*. Keydown is OK, your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You assign a value to *keysElements*  but then later reference *keysElement*, which would be undefined. Change the assignment from *var keysElements = ...*  to *var keysElement = ...*.

I'm also assuming you have an HTML document that contains elements *stopped* and *keyPressed*, e.g.:

```
    <div id="stopped"></div>
    <div id="keyPressed"></div>
```

those elements will be necessary in order for the Javascript to work properly.

Comment: Yes i am using those html commands.

Your suggestion did get it to register a key press. However, it doesn't change back to Keys not pressed. How would I do that?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Your suggestion worked and I also changed the keysPressed() method to another window.addEventListener() so that it takes "keyup" and displays the appropriate text. Thanks all for your help

Comment: You're welcome. If my response did answer your question, as you have indicated, please consider accepting it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing a keypress in the window or in a text field? 
For window, try something like this with jQuery if you like

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    //do something
});
```

If you want it on an text field, try

```
$( "#target_input_field" ).keypress(function() {
  //do something
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: I am not sure how to do jQuery with my code on codepen.io. i am not sure if it is able to be used

Comment: Please don't answer with a library that is neither tagged nor mentioned in the question, especially when it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The user mentioned javascript. jQuery is library of javascript and in my opinion a great one, so I mentioned it. From what I understood, OP was trying to do something when a key is pressed so I thought I could show the jQuery way, which I find easier. Thats all :)